# Replace term archives with static pages

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy

I need to make different pages for different Woocommerce product categories with each having different look and functionality. Defining templates for each term archive would make it difficult for my client to change things, and I'd like to make static pages for these terms which could allow use of a page builder.

I tried using `archive_template` filter but it apparently can't be used with static pages.

I'm also thinking about rewrite rules but I don't have knowledge about them, and don't want a redirect either.

Comment: The good option I think to create `taxonomy-product_cat.php` and use term meta for conditional output. But I wonder how you can customize look and functionality using page builder?

Comment: Maybe the other way around would be an option: including the terms in a static page. Does the "Page builder" plugin include an option to show a terms list?

Comment: @engelen I can easily create such static pages, but the archives would still exist which can be navigated to, and won't have the custom look these static pages would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work if library functions are used everywhere.

```
function custom_term_archive_link($url, $term, $taxonomy) {
    if($taxonomy != 'product_cat') { return $url;}

    if( $term->name == 'my_term' ) {
        $url = 'my_term_static_url';
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter('term_link', 'custom_term_archive_link', 99, 3);
```